# How to animate a pygame character walking when i click to move

Tags: python, animation, pygame

I am new to pygame, and am making a game. I have a character and i am trying to make the legs move. There are 2 pictures of it and how to i make them switch?
the character is blue wizard. can anyone help? Thank you all

```
import pygame
import time
time_start = time.time()
seconds = 0
pygame.init()
time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
timeStep = 1000
display_width = 1500
display_height = 750
originx = 0
originy = 0
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Game')
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
dollarBill = pygame.image.load('DollarBill.png')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
killed = False
manImg = pygame.image.load('Wizard1Front.png')
manImgt = pygame.image.load('Wizard1Front.png')
wfo = True
def dollarbill(dx,dy):
    gameDisplay.blit(dollarBill, (dx,dy))
def blueWizard(x,y):
    if wfo == True:
        gameDisplay.blit(manImg, (x,y))
    else:
        gameDisplay.blit(manImgt, (x,y))
x =  (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)
dx =  (display_width * 0.45)
dy = (display_height * 0.8)
#key response
key_left = False
key_right = False
key_up = False
key_down = False
right_ctrl = False
ctrl_left = False
ctrl_right = False
ctrl_up = False
ctrl_down = False
while not killed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        ############################
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                key_left = True
                ctrl_left = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                key_right = True
                ctrl_right = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                key_up = True
                ctrl_up = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                key_down = True
                ctrl_down = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RCTRL:
                right_ctrl = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                key_left = False
                ctrl_left = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                key_right = False
                ctrl_right = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                key_up = False
                ctrl_up = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                key_down = False
                ctrl_down = False
        ######################
    ##what the keys do
    if key_right == True and x < (display_width - 74):
        x += 2.5
    if key_left == True and x > 0:
        x += -2.5
    if key_up == True and y > 0:
        y += -2.5
    if key_down == True and y < (display_height - 113):
        y += 2.5
    if right_ctrl == True:
        dx += 20
    if ctrl_left == True:
        dx += -2.5
    if ctrl_right == True:
        dx += 2.5
    if ctrl_up == True:
        dy += -2.5
    if ctrl_down == True:
        dy += 2.5
   ##extra logic
    if dx > (display_width) or  dy > (display_height):
        dx = x
        dy = y
        right_ctrl = False
    if dx < (originx) or dy < (originy):
        dx = x
        dy = y
        right_ctrl = False
    gameDisplay.fill(black)
    blueWizard(x,y)
    dollarbill(dx,dy)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

While this example *may* work for a simple two image moving sprite, what you really want to do is look into using a sprite sheet.

Sprite sheets are, classically, how movement is done in games (original NES, Sega, etc).

The basic idea is that you have one big image of all the possible images for your sprite.  Then you, using code, assign specific chunks of that big image to new images.  Then you place those images in an array.  As your player moves, you increase your array index and then reset to 0 when you reach the end.

How you chose which image (index) to display can be defined either by placement on the map (x or y position), current velocity, or some other attribute.

You can even change which image array you used based on the player state.  Meaning, you could have one array of images for walking, another for running, and anther for jumping.  You can determine which array based on a flag or state object.

Generally, for good walking motion you want at least 6 images in your array.

For more info on sprite sheets in PyGame, check out their wiki: https://pygame.org/wiki/Spritesheet

For an example of sprite sheets, check out Spriters Resource: http://www.spriters-resource.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
wfo = False
def blueWizard(x,y):
    if wfo == True:
        gameDisplay.blit(manImg, (x,y))
    else:
        gameDisplay.blit(manImgt, (x,y))
```

If this is your displaying thing for character then you can do:

```
wfo = False
def set_wfo():
    global wfo #you can now use wfo if any other functions
set_wfo()
def blueWizard(x,y):
    if wfo == True:
        gameDisplay.blit(manImg, (x,y))
        wfo = False
    else:
        gameDisplay.blit(manImgt, (x,y))
        wfo = True
```

I'm not on PC so I cant't check it, but I hope it works :), maybe not.
Now when I'm looking at it, you probably should not use this function but instead just replace place where you calling it with it's code, there are no real use for this function it only complicating things...
Also insted of `if a == True:` You can use `if a:`

And instead of

```
key_left = False
key_right = False
key_up = False
key_down = False
right_ctrl = False
ctrl_left = False
ctrl_right = False
ctrl_up = False
ctrl_down = False
```

You can have

```
key_left, key_right, key_up, key_down, right_ctrl, ctrl_left, ctrl_right, ctrl_up, ctrl_down = [False]*9
```

But I would move what the keys does into the checking system where you are browsing thrue events instead, it would be much shorter and nothing else would change really...

Look at [pygame.sprite.Group](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) as well, they are very useful. Anything I didn't mention?